# How to take Screenshot in APPIUM if screenshot is RESTRICTED in Native App

Tags: appium, screenshot, appium-android, android-uiautomator, uiautomatorviewer

I am working on Automation of one native app through Java & Appium. Screenshot is restricted in that app so I am not able to take screenshot and also not able to inspect element through UIAutomator. Is there any way to solve this issue.

Comment: Could you please post the appium logs while your taking screenshot ?

Answer (score 0):

Try java way of taking screen shot instead of apache commons

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.File;

public void takeScreenShot(String fileName) {

    try {
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        Rectangle screenRectangle = new Rectangle(screenSize);
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(screenRectangle);
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File(fileName));
        System.out.println("saved.."+fileName);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I have to take APP screenshot when running appium scripts. This piece of code will not work

Answer (score 0):

Try this method and call it when you want to take the screenshot, this will create the screenshot with the name passed to the method in your project directory.

```
public void takeScreenshot(String screenShotName) {

    File file  = ((TakesScreenshot)appDriver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    try {
        FileUtils.copyFile(file, new File(screenShotName + ".jpg"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

A bit of explanation on the same is been provided here. see if this helps

https://developers.perfectomobile.com/display/TT/Capturing+screen+shots+using+Appium

Answer (score 0):

Try Get Source function from Appium

```
String pageSource = driver.getPageSource();
```

Reference: https://appium.io/docs/en/commands/session/source/